# Why do I have to remember to upgrade linux-tools-5.4.0-*-generic each time there's a kernel upgrade?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

Xubuntu 18.04

I use `linux-tools-5.4.0-*-generic` especially for `perf stat`. But, whenever there's a kernel upgrade, I have to remember to install the `linux-tools` package that corresponds to the new kernel. Seems like there should be a package I could install that would trigger an upgrade on each kernel change. If not, why not?

Comment: Xubuntu 18.04 LTS with HWE enabled defaults to the 5.4 kernel (with HWE disabled it'll use the GA 4.15 kernel).  How did you install the 5.4 kernel as everything should be automatic if you are using 5.4 via enabling HWE.

Comment: @guiverc Ah ha!  Silly me!  You have to install the `linux-tools-generic-hwe-18.04` and that installs the correct version.  My bad!

Answer (score 3):

To attempt to summarize:

- I do have `linux-generic-hwe-18.04`. I believe it was automatically installed because I installed an LTS point release
- `linux-tools-generic` depends on the `linux-tools` for the GA kernel (currently 4.15.0-117-generic), so that won't help me
- I *just* installed `linux-tools-generic-hwe-18.04`, which currently depends on the linux tools package I installed "by hand". Hopefully, when the HWE kernel upgrades, I'll get the corresponding tools package

Googling "linux generic kernel hwe" just now led me to a good explanation on the Ubuntu Wiki [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Thanks to all who answered!

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like there should be a package I could install that would
> trigger an upgrade on each kernel change.

I believe there is. Please do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-tools-generic
```

You should be all set.

Comment: The `linux-tools-generic` package is suggested by `cpupower` after a kernel upgrade, however I've found it doesn't actually keep the tools up-to-date. I still need to install a kernel specific version after every kernel upgrade.